# Matlab script to extract data from text files

Tags: database, matlab, matrix, slice

I am trying to extract coordinates of an atom from multiple datasets.
The text files are formatted like this:

```
    1234
generated by l4zyMF
O    1.234567    2.345678    3.456789    1.234567    2.345678    3.456789
H    7.654321    8.765432    9.876543    7.654321    8.765432    9.876543
...
```

Right now I'm trying to extract the 6 values for the first row O to a seperate array with a for-loop, but i just get an error message. Here is my current script:

```
Oxy = zeros(200,7)
for n=1:200
    fid = fopen('your\dir\here.dat','rt');
    data = textscan(fid,'%s %f %f %f %f %f %f','headerLines',2);
    fclose(fid);

    Oxy(3,:) = (data);
end
```

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Please add data and code to your question in written form so we can try it out.

Comment: Also, what is the actual error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work:

```
...
Oxy(3,:) = (data)
...
```

You are trying to assign a cell array to a matrix.
Also you don't necessarily need a loop to get the data with [`textscan`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

To get a `200x6` matrix of of all values use [`cell2mat`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html):

```
fid = fopen('your\dir\here.dat','rt');
data = textscan(fid,'%s %f %f %f %f %f %f','headerLines',2);
fclose(fid);
Oxy = cell2mat(data(2:end))
```

> Oxy =
>
> 1.2346   2.3457   3.4568   1.2346   2.3457   3.4568
>    7.6543   8.7654   9.8765   7.6543   8.7654   9.8765